# Incorrect modulo results in lua

Tags: lua, modulo

I am confused as to how I get the below results.  If mod is supposed to return the "remainder".  The below are lua interpreter results.

```
> 278 % 1
0
> 278 % 2
0
> 278 % 3
2
> 278 % 4
2
> 278 % 5
3
> 278 % 6
2
> 278 % 7
5
> 278 % 8
6
> 278 % 9
8
> 278 % 20
18
> math.fmod(278,20)
18
```

Comment: None of this looks out of line with the understanding of mod as "remainder". (That's an oversimplified definition, but works well enough til negative numbers get involved.) What were you expecting?

Comment: My mistake.  I was expecting something else.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the output is correct:

```
278 = 278 * 1 + 0
278 = 139 * 2 + 0
278 = 92 * 3 + 2
278 = 69 * 4 + 2
278 = 55 * 5 + 3
278 = 46 * 6 + 2
278 = 39 * 7 + 5
278 = 34 * 8 + 6
278 = 30 * 9 + 8
278 = 15 * 18 + 8
```

In every example we see `278 = quotient * n + remainder`, for `n` = 2,3,..,9,18.

The modulo operation gives you the remainder of an [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)